# using rep function to create repetition multiple times

Tags: r, rep

I did the following:

```
season<-rep(c("aut","win","sum"), each=520)
```

When I do this, I get `aut` repeated 520 times followed by `win` repeated 520 times and then `sum` repeated 520 times. I want to do this 16 times i.e `aut` 520, `win` 520, `sum` 520 and then again `aut` 520, `win` 520, `sum` 520 and again......16 times. Could anyone advise me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With one expression you can use both the `times` and `each` arguments:

```
rep(c("aut","win","sum"), each=520, times=16)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
rep(rep(c("aut","win","sum"), each=520), times=16)
```

?